# URI Routing not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I started working on a platform on CodeIgniter thanks to my work. The platform was started since before, so i just took the project. The thing is that i hadn't work with CI, so i just had a fast tutorial, and started developing based on how the platform was built. Now, to start, i decided to make a new page to to put a list of objects and understand a little how the PHP communicated with the HTML. The problem is that, when i go to the URL that i defined on routes.php, it gives an error "Requested resource does not exist", and i don't know what i'm doing wrong, while something similar works on other modules of the platform.

The files i'm using are:

**list.php**

```
// stuff
        <?php if (has_access('agroindustrias')): ?>
            <li class="<?php get_li_class('agroindustrias', $active); ?>" >
                <a href="<?php echo base_url('administracion/agroindustria'); ?>">Agroindustrias</a>
            </li>
        <?php endif ?>
// stuff
```

**agroindustria.php**

```
<?php 
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) {
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
}

class Agroindustria extends MY_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('agroindustria_model', 'agroindustria');
    }

    public function index($offset = 0)
    {
        $data['links'] = $this->paginate($this->agroindustria, 'agroindustrias', $offset);
        $data['permisos'] = $this->getPermissions('usuario');
        $data['active'] = 'usuarios';
        $data['agroindustrias'] = $this->agroindustria->limit($this->limit, $offset)->get_all();
        $data['submenu'] = $this->load->view('administracion/menu', $data, true);

        $this->template->write_view('content', 'administracion/agroindustrias/list', $data);
        $this->template->render();
    }

}
```

**routes.php**(Updated with all the file, only the one before "reportes" doesn't work)

```
$route['administracion/agroindustria'] = 'agroindustria/index';
```

My URL is: http://localhost/work/administracion/agroindustria

The other controllers works with something similar, reason that i don't know what i'm doing wrong, if i still need to add something to another file, or if something that i wrote is wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can I take it that the index.php file is in the work folder?

Comment: Yes, inside application folder.

Comment: Can you output the whole of your routes file?

Comment: Message updated.

Comment: Do you have a remap method in My_Controller ?

Comment: I'm not very sure, i'm new with CI, and i did not understand very well the part of remap, but now that you say that, i think that i found where could be the problem, i'll try to solve it, and if i succed, then i'll come and answer, if not, i'll update the question later. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After the things that @Antony told me to check, i was able to find the error, it wasn't actually an error, just that the people before worked very much in the platform, that i did not undertand the mothodology to add new modules to the platform. All that i needed to do was register the new module, and the platform added the new URL as i wanted. Thanks Antony for your help!

Comment: No problem - glad I could help :o)

Answer (score 0):

1st of all rename agroindustria.php to Agroindustria.php if 1st letter not in upper case

if you are using method like this

```
public function index($offset = 0){
  ....
  ....
  ....
}
```

then you need to change routes like

```
$route['administracion/agroindustria/(:num)'] = 'agroindustria/index/$1';
```

and url

```
http://localhost/work/administracion/agroindustria/0
```

**The best solution is change in your controller**

```
//if offset not change
public function index(){
  $offset = 0;
  ....
  ....
  ....
}

//if your offset depend upon 3rd segments of URL then
public function index(){
  $offset = if($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
  ....
  ....
  ....
}
```